# Create and update item list at same time in Sharepoint 2013 REST API using Knockout JS

Tags: sharepoint-server, knockoutjs

I'm trying to bulk create and update a SharePoint list using the following JS. When I use `"X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",` I get an error- `the type sp.listitementitycollection does not support http patch method`. I am getting duplicate entries in the list when I don't use `"X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH".`

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var sharepointBaseUrl = "https://sites.sprint.com/network/tpsd/trp/";
var sharepointTaskListUrl = sharepointBaseUrl + "_api/lists/getbytitle('Test2')";



function Task(sharepointItem) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = sharepointItem.ID;

    self.title = ko.observable(sharepointItem.Title);
    self.isDone = ko.observable(sharepointItem.IsDone);
}



function TaskListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
    self.incompleteTasks = ko.computed( function() { return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.tasks(), function(task) { return !task.isDone() }); });

    // Operations

    self.addTask = function() {
        var task=new Task({ Title: this.newTaskText()});
        self.tasks.push(task);
        self.newTaskText("");
    };


    self.save = function() { 
                                for (var i=0, len=self.tasks().length; i<len; i++)
                                {
                                    self.saveTask(self.tasks()[i]);
                                }
                                alert("yes");
                            };


    //push data back to SP list

      self.saveTask = function(task)  {
                        //update existing 
        $.ajax({
            url: sharepointBaseUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "contentType": "text/xml"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var requestData = ko.toJSON({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Test1ListItem' }, 'Title': task.title(), 'IsDone': task.isDone()});
                var myvar = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
                $.ajax({
                    url: sharepointTaskListUrl + "/items?$select=ID",
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {     
                        "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "content-length": requestData.length,
                        "X-RequestDigest": myvar,
                        "IF-MATCH": "*"
                    },
                    data: requestData,
                    success: function (data) { alert("YAY!: " + data) },
                    error: function (data) { alert("ERROR: " + data.responseText) }
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            }
        });
    };



 //load data from SharePoint list
    $.ajax( {
            url: sharepointTaskListUrl + "/items", 
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) 
                     {
                         var items = data.d.results;
                         items.forEach( function(item) { self.tasks.push(new Task(item)); } );
                     },
            error: function (data) { alert("ERROR: " + data) }
            } );
}

ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());


</script>
```

HTML

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/css/default.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/o.min.js"></script>



<div class="codeRunner"><br/>

<h3>Tasks</h3>

<form data-bind="submit: addTask">
    Add task: <input data-bind="value: newTaskText" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>

<ul data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
        <input data-bind="value: title, disable: isDone" />
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTask">Delete</a>
    </li> 
</ul>

You have <b data-bind="text: incompleteTasks().length">&nbsp;</b> incomplete task(s)
<span data-bind="visible: incompleteTasks().length == 0"> - it's water time!</span>

<br/>
<button data-bind="click: $root.save">Save</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint REST API does not do PATCH

You have to use a POST

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints

Comment: I used "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE" but still getting the same error. Is it something to do with the "IF-MATCH": "*"??